# What does "profit off" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And like other teenagers, Sridharan enjoys video games, though he's
>   trying to find a way to **profit off** of that interest too. He owns an
>   eSports team, in the hope it will take off amid the wave of popularity
>   for video game competitions.

<sup>([Source: CNN Money](http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/26/investing/16-year-old-investor-tesla-netflix-sudarshan-sridharan/index.html?iid=hp-grid-dom))</sup>

Comment: You just need the dictionary definition of "profit" as a verb. American English often uses "off of" as a preposition where British English uses other prepositions but I don't think that affects anything here. (E.g., "profit off of" -> "profit from"; "based off of" -> "based on".)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Profit off** means making a profit; earning money.

Comment: @haile Please don't leave comments saying just "thanks". Express your thanks by voting the answer up.